# Block process from using port

Tags: networking

For some reason, Foxit Reader likes to listen on port 23119. I don't know why it does this.

I want to block a specific process (Foxit Reader) from using a specific port (23119), becacuse it interferes with other programs that use this port (and actually do something useful).

How can I do it?

Comment: Maybe one day https://github.com/evilsocket/opensnitch would work, but there does not seem to be any release yet

Comment: @SebastianStark Cool! It's not packaged, but it provides instructions for building it from source. The [main site](https://www.opensnitch.io/) links to that GitHub page for downloading. Do you recommend against using it? If not, do you want to post an answer about it?

Comment: I have never tried it, so it does not feel right to recommend it. I do not even know it can prevent a process from _listening_ on a port.

Comment: @user535733 Unfortunately, FoxitReader has the nicest interface for PDF annotation on Linux. Okular is also good, but it requires a lot of KDE libraries that I do not wish to install.

Comment: How are you determining it's using the port? Just tried it an in my case it doesn't listen on the network, just some unix sockets that are probably for internal use of QT and should not interfer with something else.

Comment: @SebastianStark `netstat`

Answer (score 2):

Here are four ways. Pick one you like best.

- [IPTables](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo) (the Linux Firewall) can intercept inbound packets, so the listener never receives them. IPTables is part of the Linux kernel, included with every install of Ubuntu. Several simpler frontends to IPTables (ufw, gufw) are in the Ubuntu repositories. This is the easiest method for most users...however your case is unusual (port conflict), so it may not work for you.
- An [AppArmor rule](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/AppArmor) could prevent port use by an individual program...if/when this functionality is finally implemented (See [LP:796588](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apparmor/+bug/796588)). However, the act of prevention might crash the program.
- The application itself may offer a setting. You may need to approach the upstream developers and ask nicely for this. They might say yes, or not - they might have the listener there for a very good, innocent reason.
- When using open source software, you can edit the source and recompile. Of course, this requires many requisite skills, and is recommended for fairly advanced users only.

Since your case is a port conflict (two applications trying to use the same port), one possible solution is to start the application you want bound to the port first. After the port is bound, then you are free to start Foxit Reader.

Comment: As far as I know AppArmor can confine network traffic only at socket level, not port level. So you could block it from using TCP, but not a specific port.

Comment: If you block the port with IPTables, it will also not be possible to use it with another program, as OP wants.

Comment: @SebastianStark edited the answer to address your great input.

Comment: Yes I believe that @Sebastian Stark is correct  on using apparmor for port blocking.  However, one could write a rule to block network access from foxit altogether.